# Multiple match with same name - Unity Match Maker

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

For establishing match making service, I was using this code:
[NetworkMatch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.html)

Everything working properly for me, except both players can able to create room with same name and become host.

Unity Match making API not restricting them from creating match with same name because its already exist.

So how to restrict players from creating same name match again if already exist? If same match name exist then they require to join it rather than creating their side new match.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to calling [`CreateMatch()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.CreateMatch.html), call [`ListMatches()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.Match.NetworkMatch.ListMatches.html) (passing the same `matchName` you will pass to `CreateMatch()` in `ListMatches()`'s `matchNameFilter` argument). If you get a match with the same name returned, don't call `CreateMatch()` and have the user enter a new match name.

Comment: yes I think this will be work for me :) Let me try this and reply back to me but this kind of feature Unity should require to integrate by default within their API...

Comment: Yeah I would think so too.